# How to add a notification on the app tab of the Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox4

The FF4 delivers an app tab feature and it looks like both Gmail and Twitter have some notification code when a new mail or tweet come the app tab would look like a litter lighter.
Does any know how to operate the app tab with the notification?
I can see the code of a pinned application of IE9 with similar function. But I could not run into any document of FF.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean that you're building a website and you want to let Firefox notify the user on an event when the tab is pinned?

I'm fairly certain Firefox does it when the website's `<title>` is changed. For instance on Twitter, when there's a new tweet, the title is changed from "Twitter / Home" to "(1) Twitter / Home". Firefox notices this and notifies the user.

So really, any javascript function that changes `<title>` will make it work.

I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you adlawson. I can confirm that changing the title indeed makes the tab 'glow'.

Comment: Does this also work with the Chrome browser?  If so, then this answers this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587312/browser-tab-change-notification-like-when-you-get-a-new-gmail-e-mail-or-a-new-twe