# Browser tab change notification like when you get a new gmail e-mail or a new tweet in Twitter

Tags: javascript, html, browser, dom-events

In Chrome and Firefox, whenever I get a new email the inactive tab displays a very subtle notification. Basically, it just shines a little. In Chrome is shines from left to right as if someone is shining a flashlight on the tab.

It also does this when your are on the Twitter homepage, and a new tweet shows up.

I'm sure it is some Javascript function, but I can't seem to find it, because I don't think I am asking the question right.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Maybe this - change the title - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644897/how-to-add-a-notification-on-the-app-tab-of-the-firefox-4

Comment: Yeah, that makes perfect sense...just change the title...and yes you are right, I have picked unclear words...for some reason, I couldn't seem to get my words right...thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a notification on the app tab of the Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644897/how-to-add-a-notification-on-the-app-tab-of-the-firefox)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I [posted an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644897/how-to-add-a-notification-on-the-app-tab-of-the-firefox-4/5650249#5650249) to a similar question (thanks [@Jacob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119549/jacob)) a while back (about Firefox, not Chrome). The answer works in Chrome as well.

> Do you mean that you're building a website and you want to let Firefox notify the user on an event when the tab is pinned?
>
> I'm fairly certain Firefox does it when the website's `<title>` is
>   changed. For instance on Twitter, when there's a new tweet, the title
>   is changed from "Twitter / Home" to "(1) Twitter / Home". Firefox
>   notices this and notifies the user.
>
> So really, any javascript function that changes `<title>` will make it
>   work.
>
> I hope that helps

Just noticed the post was linked in a comment, so thanks [@planetjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/79207/planetjones) too!

Comment: Thanks for the original answer...you'll get double points for one answer...I would mark this as a dupe, but I think the terminology is different enough to leave it as is...