# How do I make a tab highlight with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to know how to make a Tab highlight everytime an event happens, in this case, it would be a call. So, if the user isn't in my website in the moment, he will know that a event happenned. My `useEffect` looks like the following:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (newCall < calls.length){
    setHighlight(true)
    setNewCall(calls.length)
  }
}, [calls.length])
```

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587312/browser-tab-change-notification-like-when-you-get-a-new-gmail-e-mail-or-a-new-tw

Comment: Yeah, kind of it. But, when I click back on the tab, I'd like the notifications to disappear

Comment: I believe you want to use `window.onfocus` as well as the `document.title` property. I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
   if (newCall < calls.length){
   setHighlight(!'your state name')
   setInterval(()=>setHighlight(!'your state name'),2000)
   setNewCall(calls.length)
 }
 }, [calls.length])
```

The above fragment of code sets highlight and so does the user knows that an event has happened and after 2 seconds the highlight will be returned to the initial state.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the solution is a combination of:

[Browser tab change notification like when you get a new gmail e-mail or a new tweet in Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7587312/browser-tab-change-notification-like-when-you-get-a-new-gmail-e-mail-or-a-new-tw)

and

[Detect If Browser Tab Has Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389328/detect-if-browser-tab-has-focus)

```
useEffect(() => {
   window.onfocus = function(){
      document.title = "Original Title"
   }
   return () => {
       window.onfocus = null;
   }
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  if (newCall < calls.length){
    document.title = `Original Title (${calls.length} calls)`
  }
}, [calls.length])
```